# Django filter objects by Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, view

I have troubles with filtering objects . The objects are displaying in all lists but I have set Foreign key for specific list . Is there any solutions ?

**models.py**

```
class Lists(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)  

class ListsItem(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now,blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)   
    main_list=models.ForeignKey(Lists, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
lists = Lists.objects.order_by('date')
listitems = ListsItem.objects.filter(main_list__in=lists).order_by('date')
```

**template**

```
{% if lists %}
{% for list in lists %}

{{list.title}}


{% if listitems %}
{% for listitem in listitems %}

{{listitem.title_item}}


{% endfor %}   
{% endif %}


{% endfor %}  
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of 2 seperate lists you could fetch your objects inside the template for each `Lists`-object:

```
{% for list in lists %}
...
{% for item in list.listsitem_set.all %}

... do something with related items

{% endfor %}
...
```

Furthermore to improve the queries you can work with `prefetch_related`, like:

```py
lists = Lists.objects.order_by('date').prefetch_related('listsitem_set')
```

And if you don't want to individually set `order_by`, just add `ordering` to the models `Meta`-class.